# join two dataframe on date column and add new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes.

Frame

[image]

df_stock

[image]

I want to join both on date column. So that where there is same date in df_stock, the innovationscore column value should be populated. Like in df_stock, where Date is 2020-10-19, 1 should be populated in InnovationScore column. What I need after joining is Date, Open, Close and InnovationScore columns.
What I have done is.

```
df_stock.join(frame, lsuffix='Date', rsuffix='Date')
```

which results in this which is not intended. I don't want DateDate column and NAN. if not value in InnovationScore, it should be 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df_stock.merge(frame, on='Date', how='left').fillna({'InnovationScore':0})
```

Or with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = df_stock.merge(frame, on='Date', how='left')
df['InnovationScore'] = df['InnovationScore'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: @shahidhamdam - then add `how='left'` for left join, added to answer.

Comment: Hey Thank you, It is working,
Can you also have a look this this question. It is related to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628567/plot-point-on-time-series-line-graph

Comment: @shahidhamdam - I have only basic skills about matplotlib, so unfortunately I cannot help with this new question.